# What free secure file erasure software for Windows 10 can be used without installation?

Tags: windows, security

What downloadable [data-erasing software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_data-erasing_software) (like Eraser) for Windows 10

1. are wholly free
2. can be operated (without losing any functions) without installation like TeamViewer?
3. don't require command lines? I'm unskilled with computers or programming.

I know not to access private files or websites on [hotel public computers](https://www.forbes.com/sites/gregorymcneal/2014/07/16/hotel-business-centers-targeted-by-cybercriminals-guest-information-compromised/#75bf869edd8e) that are dangerous, but they don't allow installations. I still fancy securing deleting files even if they're not private.

Comment: Your use case almost screams "small Linux distro on USB or business card DVD/CD".  Boot a whole OS to ram, when done, reboot and leave.

Comment: @ivanivan: I have maintained such computers some years ago: the boot order will have CD and USB disabled and a BIOS password to prevent booting from CD or USB.

Comment: Are we talking about public computers? If so, it'll be a difficult one, as you don't have admin rights there, and almost every program you find about secure file erasure requires admin rights, not for installing but for normal operation.

Comment: Most people don't know "Eraser". Please explain what the software should do. And for what operating system?

Comment: @Alejandro Does my edit clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://redd.it/crd1pd that recommends

1. http://www.fileshredder.org/
2. [Eraser Portable.](https://portableapps.com/apps/security/eraser-portable)
3. [FreeCommander](https://freecommander.com/), free, portable-zip version, Wipe option.

https://freecommander.com/fchelpxe/en/Wipe.html

https://old.reddit.com/r/AskNetsec/comments/crdfzc/what_free_secure_file_erasure_software_can_be/ex7gqzv/ recommends

4. There is a portable version of [Bleachbit](https://www.bleachbit.org/) that doesn't require installation.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft SysInternals [SDelete](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sdelete) is a **free tool** by the former hacker, writer ([Windows Internals](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735684189)) and meanwhile CTO of Microsoft Azure, Mark Russinovich. He has given trainings for Microsoft employees before MS hired him. Rest assured that he knows how NTFS works.

SDelete has several options, e.g. deleting single files, whole directories or zero the free disk space in case a file was already deleted. It is basically a single EXE file, which can be run **without installation**.

Downside: it's a command line tool.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please recommend something without command lines?

Comment: Can you please respond in, by editing, your answer? Comment chains are
cumbersome to read.